# Is using limit on main query effect the sub-queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT *,(SELECT count(id) FROM riverLikes
          WHERE riverLikes.river_id = River.id) as likeCounts
FROM River
WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3)
LIMIT 10
```

my question is my sub-query runs only 10 time ( foreach row that are fetched ) or it run for every row in the "River" table ?

my "River" has lots of records and i like to have the best performance to get the rivers .

thanks.

Comment: Sub queries MUST have only one result.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Depends on where they are used. These ones (calculated field) must have no more than one, but they can be zero rows. Since this is a `count()` query it will always return one row.

Comment: I'm not a MySQL guy, but I'd assume a join would do better.

Comment: What if the answer was 'runs for every row'?

Comment: That should only run 10 times, you might also be able to turn it into a join to make it more readable. Using Explain on it should show you which is faster. Haven't tested to see if it is correct so didn't want to add as answer

Comment: @MarkusZeller subquery have one result . thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, calculated data (either subqueries or functions), is calculated for the rows that matter, being rows that are returned, or rows for which the outcome of the calculation is relevant to further filtering or grouping.

In addition, the query optimizer may do all kinds of magic, and it is unlikely that it will run the subquery many times as such. It can be transformed in such a way that all relevant information is fetched at once.

And even if it didn't do that, it all takes place within the same operation in the database SQL engine, so executing this subselect 10 times is way, way faster than executing that subselect as a separate select 10 times, because the SQL engine only has to parse and prepare it once, and doesn't suffer from roundtrip times. 
A simple select like that could easily take 30 milliseconds or so when executed from PHP, so quick math would suggest that it'd take 300ms extra to have this subselect in a 10-row query, but that's not the case, because the lion's share of those 30ms is overhead of communication between PHP and the database.

Because of the reasons mentioned above, this subselect is possibly way faster than a join, and it's a common misconception that a join is (almost) always faster.

So, to get back to your example, the subquery won't be executed for all rows in `River`, but will only be executed, probably in optimized form, for those 10 records of Rivers 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

In most production-ready RDBMS's subquery will be run only for rows which included in result set, i.e. only 10 times in your case. I think it is true for mysql too.

**EDIT:**

For assurance run

```
EXPLAIN <your query>
```

And view execution plan of your query

Comment: Points for `EXPLAIN`. I should have added that in my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in the select statement runs one time per row returned, in your sample 10 times

Comment: Check the following link, have some suggestions how to optimize your subquery adding it as join, often works better https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery